# How to generate table name by datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I realize this is syntactically bad but I figure it somewhat explains what I'm trying to do. Essentially, I have a batch job that is going to run each morning on a small table and as a part of the spec I need to create a backup prior to each load that can be accessed by a report.

What I have so far is:

```
select  *
into    report_temp.MSK_Traffic_Backup_ + getdate()
from    property.door_traffic
```

How can I make this function or should I consider doing this a better way?

Comment: Actually, would using an exec() and executing as a string be a good approach to this?

Comment: yes - Compile your sql as a string variable then exec it. The other option would be to have a single backup table, but include a datetime in a new column, then just keep adding to the one table.

Comment: I actually wanted to approach this with a single backup table but the structure of the original table is likely to change with some regularity in the near future so it was difficult to have some fixed logic to do so without risking not capturing new fields (imo making a select into a more viable solution)

Comment: Any reason you're doing this? Why not just have one log table and add a date column?

Comment: @hkf See my previous comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @d CHAR(10) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'select  *
into    report_temp.MSK_Traffic_Backup_' + @d + '
from    property.door_traffic;';

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Now, you might also want to add some logic to make the script immune to error if run more than once in a given day, e.g.

```
DECLARE @d CHAR(10) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112);

IF OBJECT_ID('report_temp.MSK_Traffic_Backup_' + @d) IS NULL
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'select  *
  into    report_temp.MSK_Traffic_Backup_' + @d + '
  from    property.door_traffic;';

  PRINT @sql;
  --EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
END
```

When you're happy with the logic and want to execute the command, just swap the comments between `PRINT` and `EXEC`.

Comment: Any idea why a print would work fine, but execution would fail? I get the error message that the name 'select ... ' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @branwen85 Probably because you are saying `EXEC @sql` instead of `EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;`

Comment: Any one looking to add datetime insted of date select replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),101),'/','') + replace(convert(varchar, getdate(),108),':','')

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for this.

```
DECLARE @date datetime, @CMD varchar(1000);
SET @date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105)
SET @cmd = 'SELECT * INTO [dbo.T_TABLE_Backup_' + replace(cast(@date as varchar(11)),' ','_')+'] FROM dbo.T_TABLE'
print @cmd;
```