# How to run a query for current date for date partitioned tables?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I have a table that is partitioned by date so something like 'tablename_20191205'. Is there a way for me to run the query everyday without having to modify the date? Also how would I do this if I am using two tables.

So instead of typing,

Select * From `'tablename_20191205'`as table1 and `'tablename2_20191205'` as table2 and modifying the date everyday.

Can I do the following?

Select * From `'tablename_CurrentDate()'` and `'tablename2_CurrentDate()'`

I am not quire familiar with how to query date partitioned tabled. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.tablename*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = CONCAT('_' , FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())   
   OR _TABLE_SUFFIX = CONCAT('2_', FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', CURRENT_DATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @date char(20) = CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 100);

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'select * from table_name_'+ @date ;

PRINT @query;
```

I think this code solve your issue.

For your reference you can check out this article for more detail [How to generate table name by datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110775/how-to-generate-table-name-by-datetime)

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with BigQuery.