# How to create a backup table from a table with current date & time in sql server

Tags: sql-server

How to create a backup table from a table with current date & time in sql server.

The spaces in date & time should be replaced by underscore.

For Backup I am doing this :-

```
select * into BKP_TABLE_STUDENT
from TABLE_STUDENT
```

And for fetching DateTime I am using this :-

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 0)
```

Above gives this format -> **Mar  2 2022  4:02PM**

So, I need to combine the above datetime and the table name.

E.g. Table name will be **BKP_TABLE_STUDENT_Mar_2_2022_4_02PM**

Comment: Do note that what you have there is not a "true" backup, in the sense that it still lives in the same database and will be gone if that database is gone. The term "backup" is usually reserved for a backup of an entire database. Ensure you are taking "real" backups and storing them somewhere safely before you make table-level copies of data like this (which may still have a purpose on their own).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate table name by datetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110775/how-to-generate-table-name-by-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conactenate your table name with a formatted string.
I would prefer a 24 hour clock than AM / PM but it's your call

```
SELECT CONCAT('BKP_TABLE_STUDENT_',FORMAT(getdate(),'MMM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_tt')) as backup_name
```

returns

```
BKP_TABLE_STUDENT_Mar_02_2022_11_24_AM
```

Comment: Thanks Kendle..!

However, can you help me over how I can add the above with creating the backup of table from main table

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

`SELECT CONCAT('BKP_TABLE_STUDENT_',FORMAT(getdate(),'MMM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_tt')) as backup_name`

`SELECT *  into backup_name from TABLE_STUDENT`

Comment: Since there is already an accepted answer, I recommend adding some text that explains the code you have shared. The first code snippet is already in the accepted answer. Perhaps you can add some detail that describes why the second code snippet is useful to people looking at this post :)